# ASN1 corrupted data

Tags: c#, asn.1

I am getting following exception:

ASN1 corrupted data, The provided data is tagged with 'ContextSpecific' class value '0',
but it should have been 'Universal' class value '6'.

Following is my code:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();

                try
                {
                // This will decode public key encoded with PKCS#1. In UAT and above this flow will work.
               
                rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(
                source: Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["Authentication:Jwt:publicKey"]),
                        bytesRead: out int _
                    );

                }
                catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException ex)
                {
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.